# jxbrowser socket server hangs

Tags: sockets, jxbrowser

I have jxBrowser integrated into our java desktop application. A user on Dell Precision 7510 running Microsoft Windows 10 Pro, reports that when the application launches a separate "SocketServer" process is launched and that it uses up to 45% of his CPU.

Is there a way to customize jxBrowser to reduce this overhead? We're using jxbrowser 6.14.2

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Could you please specify what separate "SocketServer" process is meant as by default when JxBrowser is launched you should be seeing 4 processes - Java process, the main one, the rendering one and the GPU one?

The server socket is opened in JxBrowser however, it is not a separate process.